# RoR. Как передавать параметры одной модели в форму создания другой?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mvc, haml

Возник вопрос. Допустим у меня имеются 2 модели: Организация и Услуги. Связь один ко многим, т.е. у организации много услуг. Когда мы заходим на страницу конкретной организации, то у нас имеется кнопка "Создать услугу", нажимаем на нее и попадаем на страницу создания услуги, где у нас одно из полей - "Организация". Это поле задано как:

```
 .col-md-4
  .form-group
    =f.label :organization_id
    .input-group
      =f.select :organization_id, Organization.ordering.map{|c| [c.name,c.id]},{}, class: "form-control"
```

Вопрос в том, как в это поле ставить как значение по-умолчанию ту организацию, на странице которой мы нажали кнопку "Создать услугу"?

*form_for*:

```
= form_for @service do |f|
  =error_messages_for(@service)
  .row
    .col-md-4
      .form-group
        =f.label :name
        =f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control'
    .col-md-4
      .form-group
        =f.label :description
        =f.text_area :description ,class: 'form-control'
  .row
    .col-md-6
      .form-group
        =f.label :price
        .input-group
          =f.text_field :price, class: "form-control"
          %span.input-group-addon.glyphicon.glyphicon-ruble
  .row
    .col-md-4
      .form-group
        =f.label :terms
        .input-group
          =f.number_field :terms, class: "form-control"
          %span.input-group-addon РґРЅРµР№
  .row
    .col-md-4
      .form-group
        =f.label :organization_id
        .input-group
          =f.select :organization_id, Organization.ordering.map{|c| [c.name,c.id]},{}, class: "form-control"
  .actions
    = f.submit nil, class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

Comment: `form_for` как выглядит?

Comment: @D-side Добавил в описание.

Comment: Интересовала только верхушка (одна строчка с `form_for`), но она не очень всё прояснила. Что в `@service`?

Comment: А почему вы не сделали ресурс услуга вложенным по отношению к организации?

Comment: @D-side В каком смысле что в @service? Если Вы про параметры, то `:name, :price, :description, :terms, :organization_id`

Comment: @SergeiStralenia Я, видимо, много чего не знаю, но что значит вложенным по отношению к организации?

Comment: Не параметры. Как создан лежащий там объект?

Comment: @D-side Это лишь форма создания нового объекта модели Услуга. Есть строка в **organization/show.html.haml** `=link_to new_service_path(organization_id: @organization.id), class: 'btn btn-primary'` где я попадаю на страницу создания новой услуги и как один из параметров передаю id той организации на которой был. И вот как в `@service.organization_id` положить это переданное значение `@organization.id`, который я в show прописал и передал на страницу создания?

Comment: Это я понял. Чем этот объект создаётся? `Service.new`? `@organization.services.build`? Что-то ещё?

Comment: @D-side `Service.new`

Comment: @D-side сделал через `@organization = Organization.find(params[:organization_id])
    @service = @organization.services.build` . Теперь создаются и присваиваются услуги верно, но не понимаю как сделать вывод этих услуг в методе `show` у организации. Выпадает ошибка `undefined method each' for nil:NilClass`, при этом есть `= form_for [@organization, @organization.services.build] do |f|` в `organization/show` и `def create
    @organization = Organization.find(params[:organization_id])
    @service = @organization.services.build(service_params)`. Чего может не хватать для вывода услуг?

Comment: @g1roy (1) не пишите в комментариях многострочников, (2) это уже другой вопрос, оформите отдельно.